# Template re-definition error when compiled with VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm running into some sort of template re-definition error. It is not a solution-breaking error (I've found workarounds), but I'd still like to understand why the code is erroneous.

```
template <typename RandomEngine, typename RandomDistribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int> >
struct base_random_generator {
    RandomEngine generator;
    RandomDistribution distribution;
    base_random_generator(RandomEngine gen, 
                          RandomDistribution dist = RandomDistribution(0, 10))
        : generator(gen), distribution(dist) { }
    int operator()() {
        return distribution(generator);
    }
};

base_random_generator< std::mt19937 >
create_mt_generator(std::mt19937::result_type seed = std::mt19937::default_seed) {
    return base_random_generator< std::mt19937 > (std::mt19937(seed));
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 fails to compile the code above with this error:

> ... already defined in main.obj
>
> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

If I remove the create_mt_generator function, however, the error goes away and all is good again.
My main idea is to be able to pass a struct that behaves like a std::function so I can call it over and over again to get a random integer.

That function is looks something like this:

```
template <typename Container, typename RandomGenerator>
void scramble(Container c, RandomGenerator rand) { }
```

I thought it would be need to be able to create a random generator class on the fly with parameters given by the user.

Comment: Your `create_mt_generator` function returns a template object but it is *not* a template function, and thus needs a home outside the header file. You can declare it `inline` (or `static`) if you want to keep it in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Only certain types of functions should be defined in the header file:

- `inline`
- `template`
- `static`

In all other cases, put the definition in just one compilation unit, and use a forward declaration (prototype) in the header file to make it visible to other compilation units.